# setBackButtonBackgroundImage with weird appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

using this in AppDelegate.m for my custom NavBar:

```
UIImage *NavigationPortraitBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient_main"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:NavigationPortraitBackground forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
UIImage *barBackBtnImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_nav_default.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barBackBtnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

results in:

[image]

As you can see the button seems to be repeated. Button dimensions are 61x30. And the text is not centered.
If the text is shorter (e.g. Menu) the button image is cut off and if text is longer, then button is repeating.
Similar problem with buttons that have a smaller icon (30x30). The button shows fine but I can click in the button outside of the image :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are providing a resizeable image without UIEdgeInsets and without specifying the resizing style. The text on your UIBarButtonItem is actually centered! If you measure the distance on both sides of the text, you'll realize that it's the same.

If you look at the image you provide for the UIBarButtonItem:

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_nav_default.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

You're telling iOS that @"btn_nav_default.png" is a resizeable image and that it should **tile**. It's basically taking copies of your image and placing them side by side until the full width is covered. If you look at [UIImage's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll see that the default behaviour for resizableImageWithCapInsets is to tile. You will want to call `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` and pass in `UIImageResizingModeStretch` for your resizing mode.

That being said, that won't be enough. What you'll see after that is that the entire image is stretched, completely destroying your nice rounded corners. You need to provide UIEdgeInsets that tell UIImage that "you cannot stretch this section". In this case, providing `UIEdgeInsets` of `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f)` (or something similar) will work.

If you're not interested in the long explanation, copy paste this code (no guarantees that this compiles though...):

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_nav_default.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Comment: great :) now I only need an alternative for resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode: in iOS5 :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

in ios 5 after you put the insets